# How to expand column in a ListView item?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget that is used as an item in a `ListView`. It goes like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 24),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)))),
        SizedBox(width: 24),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Something",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                Text("Something2"),
                Text("Something3")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is the way I create the `ListView`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return MyItemWidget();
    },
  );
}
```

However, that yields the following result:

[image: ListView]

---

Could you please advice me on how to make the texts start vertically at the top of the item, not in the center?

As a bonus, I would be interested in how to make the yellow box take up the heigh of the whole item. **But it is not required.**

Something like this would be the desired output:

[image: Desired output 1]

or with the "bonus":

[image: Desired output 2]

Comment: Could you post also how you use this item in your ```ListView```?
First thing that comes to my mind is to set ```Padding``` of the ```ListView``` to zero, have you tried this?

Comment: Added the `ListView` widget. I tried using  `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` and it did not help :(

Comment: As far as making the yellow container take up the whole height, you could wrap the row with `IntrinsicHeight()` widget

Comment: I would not recommend to use ```IntrinsicHeight``` widget in a list since it could cause performance issues with more complex lists.
From official docs: "This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree."

Comment: zpouip already provide a way to make the yellow container take the full Hight and as for centering the text on the top you can add textAlign: TextAlign.topCenter to the text widget.

Comment: Good point good point

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I updated the question. To be honest, more important for me is the simple task of starting the text at the top of the item. Still not sure what the best way is. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `crossAxisAlignment` of your `Row` widget as in the following snippet:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 24),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)))),
          SizedBox(width: 24),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Something",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text("Something2"),
                  Text("Something3")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This works well! Though there is a possibility that the Something texts might be pretty long. Therefore I didn't want to use fixed height :( To be honest, my main use case is to have the texts at the top, I asked about the yellow container out of curiosity :)

Comment: The problem is that you set ```height``` of the blue ```Container``` to a fixed value in a ```Row``` and the other element cannot recognize it.
You can also set this line in your ```Row```:

```crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start```

Comment: This might be an even better solution if this is your main intention...

Comment: Oh, using `crossAxis` on the `Row` did not even cross my mind. I am stupid :) Of course that's exactly what I need. Can you edit that in your answer so that I can possibly accept it later?

Comment: No problems, will do :)
Glad it helped